# No implementation found for native Lcom/jp/algi/

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I try everything, but I think I have ever think OK, but it still says this error:

```
No implementation found for native Lcom/jp/algi/Corelib;.vector ([F)[F
threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
```

.cpp file >

```
 extern "C"{
   JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector
       (JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray cinput)
       {
      ////


         } 
               }
```

.h file generated by javah >

```
       JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_Corelib_vector
        (JNIEnv *, jobject, jfloatArray)
```

class where I have the native methods .java>

```
    package com.jp.algi;

      public class Corelib {

     static {
    System.loadLibrary("com_jp_algi_Corelib");
       }

// TestFileBroswerActivity(vstup_RGB);
     public native float[] vector(float[] input);
```

I calling this method throght another class..
ISnt problem in the App.mk<

```
      APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

Comment: NB the jobject received by the method isn't a class, it is an instance.

Comment: and there is a problem? I have it only called like this

Answer (score 1):

Is the library really called `libcom_jp_algi_Corelib.so`? `loadLibrary()` expects the library name without the `lib` prefix and `.so` extension.

Library name is specified in Android.mk as `LOCAL_MODULE`. It's also without `lib` and extension.

Comment: True but the problem isn't with the loadLibrary() call, it is when calling the native method. At the moment of loading the library it doesn't know what Java method signatures are supposed to exist inside it.

Comment: How can I find out if the libcom_jp_algi_Corelib.so is really called? Log: 14:20:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project FileBroswerActivity ****
sh "C:\\android-ndk-r5c\\ndk-build" all 
Install        : libcom_jp_algi_Corelib.so => libs/armeabi/libcom_jp_algi_Corelib.so
Install        : libcom_jp_algi_Corelib.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcom_jp_algi_Corelib.so

14:20:15 Build Finished (took 3s.750ms)

Comment: Check the contents of `(project)\libs\armeabi`. The library should be there, as an `.so` file.

Comment: yes there are in libs\armeabi one .co file and in the libs\armeabi\libs/armeabi-v7a/ on e .so file , these contetnts its somethink withou t readable format..

Comment: Iam tested this on S2 device , armeabi armeabi-v7a , is there problem.? becou I delte App.mk and the error is the same

Comment: ANd there is problem when i Delte syste.loadlib itds the same error, and the Library is loaded , when is not delete , I tested by Log.